# I Changed all file permissions and now my system broke. How do i fix it?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

When tinkering with permissions i accidentally broke my system.
I changed all the file permissions in the entire system. (i am a newbie, didn't know this is stupid)
I activated the root account with recovery mode. So i now have access to sudo/root commands. Everything else is still not working
For example OpenSSH doesn't work anymore

how do i revert the permissions, is it even possible?

Ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: Didi you change it really for all files in the whole system? In that case it will be much easier and quicker just to reinstall. Next time you will be more careful hopefully ;)

Comment: you would have to, at the very least, indicate what you did.....

Comment: Reinstall. That's the "easy" way. The "hard" way involves determining the correct permissions of tens of thousands of files.